# libpng -- error: Not a PNG file -- png_process_data()

Tags: c, libpng

I am attempting to write a progressive reader using libpng. I have tried to follow the code in example.c provided with libpng source but it does not work. I have also looked at [libpng doc](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter14.html). Which instructs you to use `png_set_progressive_read_fn()` in connection with `png_process_data()`. After setting up things as specified in the documentation. When I go to start the process of having the png file read I get the following error from libpng.

> Not a PNG file

Stepping through the code reveals that when `png_process_data()` goes to check the signature of the PNG file, it identifies that it is not a png file. This is very peculiar behavior since before I call my read function I verify the file is a PNG file with the following bit of code.

```
int check_png_sig(const char * file_name)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if(!fp) {
    return (0);
  }
  enum HeaderSize {Size = 8}; 
  png_byte header[Size];
  fread(header, 1, Size, fp);
  int is_png = !png_sig_cmp(header, 0, Size);
  if (!is_png) {
    fclose(fp);
    return (0);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return (1);
}
```

I close the `FILE*` and then reopen a new one in my read function so I don't have to tell libpng that I have already read 8 bytes with `png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);`. My read function is as follows.

```
int read_png_file(const char * file_name)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Reading PNG File %s\n", file_name);
  fflush(stdout);

  if (!png_ptr || !info_ptr) {
    return (0);
  }

  FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if(!fp) {
    return (0);
  }

  png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
  png_voidp user_chunkp = png_get_user_chunk_ptr(png_ptr);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call read_chunk_callback if an unknown chunk is
   * encountered
   */
  png_set_read_user_chunk_fn(png_ptr, user_chunkp, read_chunk_callback);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call read_row_callback if an known chunk is
   * encountered.
   */
  png_set_read_status_fn(png_ptr, read_row_callback);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call the specified functions on info, rows, or
   * end.
   */
  png_set_progressive_read_fn(png_ptr, user_chunkp, info_callback,
    row_callback, end_callback);

  enum Size {DataSize = 8};
  unsigned char rawbuf[DataSize];
  int process = 1;
  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
    free_png_resources();
    process = 0;
    return process;
  }

  /*
   * Check to see if libpng is confused
   */
  //png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

  while (process) {
    memset(rawbuf, 0, DataSize);
    png_process_data(png_ptr, info_ptr, rawbuf, DataSize);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return (process);
}
```

I also have a working version of a non-porgressive reader at ([non-progressive reader](http://matthewh.me/graphics/browser/pngreader)). It works just fine on my file. So it is not an issue with my file.

---

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
#include <png.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static png_structp png_ptr;
static png_infop info_ptr;
static png_bytep old_row = NULL;

/* Variable that loops untill data is read */
int run = 0;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// Callbacks
int read_chunk_callback(png_structp png_ptr, png_unknown_chunkp chunk)
{
  struct chunk
  {
    png_byte name[5];
    png_byte *data;
    png_size_t size;
  };

  return (0); /* did not recognize */
}

/*
 * This method will be called each time a row is read
 * and differs from the row_callback in that ...
 */
void read_row_callback(png_structp ptr, png_uint_32 row, int pass)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "read_row_callback\n");
}

int process_data(png_bytep buffer, png_uint_32 length)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "process_data\n");
  png_process_data(png_ptr, info_ptr, buffer, length);
  return 0;
}

void info_callback(png_structp png_ptr, png_infop info)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "info_callback\n");
  png_uint_32 width;
  png_uint_32 height;
  int         bit_depth;
  int         color_type;
  int         interlace_type;
  int         compression_type;
  int         filter_type;
  png_byte    channels;
  png_uint_32 rowbytes;
  png_bytep   signature;

  /*
   * This will get the information stored in the header
   * of the PNG file.
   */
  png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &width, &height, &bit_depth, &color_type,
    &interlace_type, &compression_type, &filter_type);

  /*
   * Get the rest of the header information.
   */
  channels = png_get_channels(png_ptr, info_ptr);
  /* This is subject to change with transformations */
  rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);
  signature = png_get_signature(png_ptr, info_ptr);

  fprintf(stdout,
    "width: %u"
    "height: %u"
    "bit_depth: %d"
    "color_type: %d"
    "interlace_type: %d"
    "compression_type: %d"
    "filter_type: %d"
    "channles: %d"
    "rowbytes: %u"
    "signature: %s", (unsigned int)width, (unsigned int)height, bit_depth, color_type,
    interlace_type, compression_type, filter_type, channels,
    (unsigned int)rowbytes, signature);
}

void row_callback(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep new_row, png_uint_32 row_num,
  int pass)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "row_callback\n");
  png_progressive_combine_row(png_ptr, old_row, new_row);
}

void end_callback(png_structp png_ptr, png_infop info)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "end_callback\n");
  run = 1;
}

/*
 * Error handler local to his translation unit
 * Used by png_create_read_struct function.
 */
void progressive_reader_error_fn(png_structp png_ptr, png_const_charp msg)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", msg);
  fflush(stderr);
  longjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr), 1);
  exit(0);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * Free PNG resources on close
 */
void free_png_resources() 
{
  png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
  png_ptr = NULL;
  info_ptr = NULL;

}

/*
 * All strings to this function must
 * be null terminated -- return 0 if
 * file is not in png format
 */
int check_png_sig(const char * file_name)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if(!fp) {
    return (0);
  }
  enum HeaderSize {Size = 8};
  png_byte header[Size];
  fread(header, 1, Size, fp);
  int is_png = !png_sig_cmp(header, 0, Size);
  if (!is_png) {
    fclose(fp);
    return (0);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return (1);
}

/*
 * Create the png_structp and png_infop
 */
int create_png_structs()
{
  png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL,
    progressive_reader_error_fn, NULL);
  if (!png_ptr) {
    return 0;
  }

  info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
  if (!info_ptr) {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
  }

  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

/*
 * This method does all the work
 */
int read_png_file(const char * file_name)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "Reading PNG File %s\n", file_name);
  fflush(stdout);

  if (!png_ptr || !info_ptr) {
    return (0);
  }

  FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if(!fp) {
    return (0);
  }

  png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
  png_voidp user_chunkp = png_get_user_chunk_ptr(png_ptr);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call read_chunk_callback if an unknown chunk is
   * encountered
   */
  png_set_read_user_chunk_fn(png_ptr, user_chunkp, read_chunk_callback);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call read_row_callback if an known chunk is
   * encountered.
   */
  png_set_read_status_fn(png_ptr, read_row_callback);

  /*
   * Tell libpng to call the specified functions on info, rows, or
   * end.
   */
  png_set_progressive_read_fn(png_ptr, user_chunkp, info_callback,
    row_callback, end_callback);

  enum Size {DataSize = 8};
  unsigned char rawbuf[DataSize];
  int process = 1;
  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
    free_png_resources();
    process = 0;
    return process;
  }

  /*
   * Check to see if libpng is confused
   */
  //png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

  while (process) {
    memset(rawbuf, 0, DataSize);
    png_process_data(png_ptr, info_ptr, rawbuf, DataSize);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return (process);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (check_png_sig("/home/matt6809/Downloads/png_image.png")) {
    if (create_png_structs()) {
      if (read_png_file("/home/matt6809/Downloads/png_image.png")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SUCCESS!!!\n");
      }   
    }
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Makefile**

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
LD = /usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -lpng

SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

TARGET = progressive

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $(TARGET)

%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean :
        rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to read the content from your file.

Replacing:

```
while (process) {
  memset(rawbuf, 0, DataSize);
  png_process_data(png_ptr, info_ptr, rawbuf, DataSize);
}
```

with

```
size_t read;
while ((read = fread(rawbuf, 1, DataSize, fp))) {
  png_process_data(png_ptr, info_ptr, rawbuf, read);
}
```

is enough to allow decoding to proceed.

I did notice one other thing: the second parameters passed to `png_set_read_user_chunk_fn()` and `png_set_progressive_read_fn()` are supposed to be arbitrary values that the callback functions can get hold of later (via `png_get_user_chunk_ptr()` and `png_get_progressive_ptr()`, respectively).

These can be set to whatever values you like (or to NULL if you don't need them), but you shouldn't be calling the `png_get_*_ptr()` functions yourself to get a value to pass to `png_set_*_fn()`.  (I think it's harmless, since they'll return NULL to start with, but it's confusing at best.)